# Why the 'info' object is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,(error,info)=>{
   if(error) console.log(error)
   console.log('Message Sent: '+info.messageId)
   console.log('Preview URL: '+nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info))
   res.redirect('contacts',{msg:'Email has been sent'})
});
```

I am using `nodemailer` to send mail, I have configured it correctly, but what could be the possible reason that I am getting `undefined` when I am logging the value of `info` into the console?

Comment: What is the output of `error`?

Comment: `info` is undefined. Cannot read property of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `info` is not being set because there is an error. You would have to confirm by looking at their [source](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer).

You can, however, account for this by changing your code slightly, like so:

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,(error, info)=>{
    if (error) {
       return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message Sent: '+info.messageId)
    console.log('Preview URL: '+nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info))
    res.redirect('contacts',{msg:'Email has been sent'})
});
```

This way if `error` is set, it will log the error and return before falling through the rest of your code. This is similar to the example on [their page](https://nodemailer.com/about/).